# Make cookie expire after 3 or 5 seconds

Tags: php

I need a cookie on my site just for a few seconds. What i tried is this:

```
$value = 12;
$cookie = setcookie("myCookie", $value, time() + 3);
```

The cookie gets created, but needs longer to expire than 3 seconds

Comment: The 'expire' argument expects the amount of seconds since the epoch. You are adding 3000 seconds (50 minutes) to the current time instead. What I think you mean to do is this: `setcookie("myCookie", $value, time() + 3);`

Comment: @AndyHenderson Thats exactly what he has coded????

Comment: The answer has since been edited. It originally said `$cookie = setcookie("myCookie", $value, time() + (3 * 1000));`

Comment: @AndyHenderson That's exactly my code. The cookie needs about 1 minutes and 10 seconds to expire with this edited code.

Comment: Remember a cookie does not actually get deleted until the next connection is made after the timeout period has expired

Comment: that's fine, i know about that,  but still it needs longer to expire.

Comment: Is this then because the time on the client is a little different to the time on the server?

Comment: well i am working on localhost at the moment ,so there should be no time difference

Comment: The same code you posted here works fine on my localhost. Can you specify the browser you are using?

Comment: I am using Chrome in Version 45.0.2454.99 m... Maybe i should add that i try to set the cookie on click of a button, i don't know if this is something important.

Comment: This sounds extremely fishy yo start with. What in the world do you need a 3 second cookie for?! Sounds like you're using the wrong tool to solve [some unrelated problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Well i find it unnecessary that you start asking if i even know what i am doing or what i need the cookie for. My question was not "For what do i need a 3 seconds cookie", so please just let this kind of anwsers be.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple time math here.

```
$value = 12;

$seconds_in_seconds = 1;
$minute_in_seconds = 60
$hour_in_seconds = 60 * 60;
$day_in_seconds = 60 * 60 * 24
$week_in_seconds = 60 * 60 * 24 * 7
  /*ect...*/
/*60 seconds in a minute. Times 2 minutes plus 10 seconds. Makes 2 minutes and ten seconds.*/
$time = time() + (2 * $minute_in_seconds) + (10 * $seconds)
$cookie = setcookie("myCookie", $value, $time);
```